# ListView - why there is a yellow gap between my widgets?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am struggling to understand why there is a yellow space between my two widgets... I am using a listView widget which use a snapshot to create a list

[image]

Here is my code

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24.0),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(
                    'My least tested  groups',
                  ),
                  Container(
                    color: Colors.yellowAccent,
                    child: SchoolList(),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
    );
  }
```

And this is the Widget

```
class SchoolList extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: myStream1,
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError) return new Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
        switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
          case ConnectionState.waiting:
            return new Text(
              'Loading...',
              style: kSendButtonTextStyle.copyWith(color: kColorText),
            );
          default:
            return new ListView(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
              children:
                  snapshot.data.documents.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
                return Container(
                    height: 100,
                    width: 100,
                    color: Colors.white,
                    child: Text('xxx'));
              }).toList(),
            );
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Can anyone understand why I have a yellow gap and more importantly how to get rid of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the `ListView` trying to applying top padding for status bar.

you can remove it by setting `padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0)` in the `ListView` widget.

Comment: This was the reason! I am not sure why it was happening and it is the first time I see this behaviour. Thank you very much for the response!